# Unable to select combobox item via arrow keys wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am using the combobox as autocomplete and updating the items source of combobox as per the text entered in the box. But when I do so, I am not able to select the combobox item using the arrow keys after entering second letter in the combobox. If I give a pre-defined data to the items source it is working perfectly.

I am performing all these task in the text changed event.

```
List<string> suggestions = new List<string> { };
suggestions.Clear();

foreach (string item in data)
{
    if((item.ToLower()).StartsWith(typedString))
    {
        suggestions.Add(item);
    }
}

if (suggestions.Count > 0)
{
    combo.ItemsSource = suggestions;
    combo.IsDropDownOpen = true;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using NeyboardNavigation commands? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigationmode.aspx

Comment: @coinbird Not working. Everything works perfectly when for the first letter and then the combobox dropdown is loaded with desired data but when I press the arrows, nothing happens

Comment: If you’re changing the `ItemsSource` while the user is interacting with the control, then you’re probably going to get some strange behavior.  It’s just not meant to be used that way.  I’d take a look at whatever third-party autocomplete controls are available—using a  `ComboBox` is not going to get you the best results.